# How to check ViewBag contains a specific string

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

In controller I have:

```
string[] checkedBoxes 
ViewBag.Funds = checkedBoxes;
```

`checkedBoxes` is posted by a form in the view page. How do I check inside the view if `ViewBag.Funds`  contains a specific string?
I tried:

```
@if (ViewBag.Funds.ContainsKey("a"))
{
               
}
```

I got this error: `RuntimeBinderException: 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'ContainsKey'`

`.Contains()` also doesn't work even though I used `@using System.Linq`

Comment: ViewBag.Funds.Contains("a")

Comment: `if (ViewBag.Funds.Any(s=>s.Contains("a")))` if you are using `System.Linq `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to cast the ViewBag property to the type first. Try this

```
@if (((string[])ViewBag.Funds).Contains("a"))
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@if (ViewBag.Funds.Any(s=>s.Contains("a"))))
{
               
}
```